# Does accessing a local final variable from a listener require check for null?

Tags: java, android, memory-management

When we have the following:

```
final TextView view = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.some_view);  

button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
    public void onClick(View v) {    
       view.setText(“blah”);    
    }   
}
```

//etc

`view` unless is `final` can not be accessed by the `onClick` method.
If this snippet is inside a method then `view` is allocated on the stack holding a reference to the heap. So in the end of the method call `view` is lost. Since the `onClick` is in the same scope the `view` is still visible. My question is: The `onClick` can be called at any time. Marking it as `final` does it ensure that `view` will not be null when the listener runs? Or is a check for null required? And why is that the case?

Comment: *Marking it as final does it ensure that view will not be null when the listener runs?* of course not ... `layout.findViewById(R.id.some_view)` may still returns null

Comment: @Selvin:but I won't be calling that in the listener

Comment: final has nothing to do with null check ... `final Object name = null;` is pretty valid ...  `layout.findViewById(R.id.some_view);` my return null so obviously `view`  can be null

Comment: @Selvin: Why would it be null since it is a strong reference? That's what I am trying to understand

Comment: *Why would it be null since it is a strong reference?*  I would recommend some java's basics course ... it seems like you do not understand what `final` keyword does

Comment: @Jim why not just call a method in "onClick" that resides in the surrounding regular class (not the anonymous one). That way you need not mark it as final.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that findViewById() will return null, if your layout doesn't contain R.id.some_view. So you probably need to check that for null.
Where to check for null depends on your app logic. Anonymous OnClickListener object will create inner "view" copy, so even if outer "view" goes out of scope, the listener will still hold reference to the "view" variable.
Where to check for null is your choice, but if you findViewById() return null then you probably should not create click a listener.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your final code

But This Textview is not null.

Maybe layout don't have textview

You have to check textview your layout.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R
            .layout.activity_main);

    Button button =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    final TextView view = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.some_view);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            view.setText("Hello world");
        }
    });

}
```